# Can a Cleric use a wand that's of a Domain spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, cleric

I was going over the specs for one of my potential characters and I love the spell Enlarge Person. It's insane. As a Cleric under Cayden Cailean, my character can use that spell, but a standard Cleric wouldn't be able to. The question is: can my character use a wand of Enlarge Person?

Answer (score 14):

**It's on your personal spell list, so yeah**

Any spell your class has access to, or that you can cast natively, you can use a wand of (except in specific cases that call out the lack of availability, such as specialist wizard). Of course, you can always make a *Use Magic Device* check to try and use the wand even if you can't use it normally.

EDIT:

From the [Wand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wands) entry:

> Activation: Wands use the spell trigger activation method, so casting a spell from a wand is usually a standard action that doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity. (If the spell being cast has a longer casting time than 1 action, however, it takes that long to cast the spell from a wand.) To activate a wand, a character must hold it in hand (or whatever passes for a hand, for non-humanoid creatures) and point it in the general direction of the target or area. A wand may be used while grappling or while swallowed whole.

From the [Spell Trigger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Spell-Trigger) entry:

> Spell Trigger: Spell trigger activation is similar to spell completion, but it's even simpler. No gestures or spell finishing is needed, just a special knowledge of spellcasting that an appropriate character would know, and a single word that must be spoken. Spell trigger items can be used by anyone whose class can cast the corresponding spell. This is the case even for a character who can't actually cast spells, such as a 3rd-level paladin. The user must still determine what spell is stored in the item before she can activate it. Activating a spell trigger item is a standard action and does not provoke attacks of opportunity.

Note that strictly speaking, by the above wording, you can use wands of *anyone's* domain spells. I do not suggest trying this, as you may get hit by the book.

Comment: On the last point, I grok that as *specifically* the *item wielder's* class--e.g. Clr A has *enlarge person* as a domain spell so Clr A's cleric *class* allows using a wand of it, but Clr B doesn't have it as a domain spell, so Clr B's cleric *class* doesn't allow using a *wand* of it. It's actually a rather elegant answer to the question of whether a *D&D 3.5* Clr can use wands of domain spells (which wasn't said outright until the *Rules Compendium*).

Comment: I think the _"anyone's domain"_ might be too broad given the whole issue with archetypes. Archetype are basically "specialists", "domains" & "bloodlines" for other classes and by that wording a Ranger whose archetype never gets spell access could still use wands. This sounds like the exact type of thing that needs an errata for clarification. This seems like a pretty obvious clarification

Comment: But RAW doesn't deal in what it needs, only in what *is*. If an errata comes out I'll gladly edit the answer; in the meantime, the RAW on the broad wording stands. Talk to Paizo, not me >.>